# MSBuild not always creating .precompiled files

Tags: msbuild, aspnet-compiler

I'm having an issue with my Build server. I'm calling MSBuild for Building a Web Project, the process runs, it even shows `ASPNETCOMPILER` warnings for some views, the views are getting 'cleaned' but the .precompiled files and DLLs are not getting saved to the bin folder.

Some information:
MSBuild version: 16.11.0.36601 (VS 2019 default version), Server: Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

This is the command I'm using (works on other machines):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "[PATH]\Web.sln" /t:Clean;Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:BuildInParallel=true /p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:EnableUpdateable=false /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

The main issue is I need MSBuild to generate the files always on every run and it's happening once in a while.

Some other parameters I've used with no success:

`/p:OutputPath=bin`

`/p:UseMerge=true /p:WDPMergeOption="MergeAllOutputsToASingleAssembly" /p:SingleAssemblyName="WebCompiled"`

`Build` instead of `Rebuild`

I've tried to run the command also with Admin permissions with my Administrator account and the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not having success in finding the cause of the inconsistent behavior, I had to set up a new server to run the compilation.